# Failed to find trusted certificate. As a consequence: SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, ssl, spring-boot, https, tls1.2

There are client and server modules. Both modules are deployed in embedded tomcat containers on 443 and 8443 ports (https). For each module, the following configuration example is specified (in spring-boot application-https.properties):

```
#client
server.port=443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:client-keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=client-keystore-pass
server.ssl.key-password=client-key-pass
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:client-truststore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=client-truststore-pass

#server
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:server-keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=server-keystore-pass
server.ssl.key-password=server-key-pass
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:server-truststore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=server-truststore-pass
```

The keystores and certificates are generated as follows:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias server-keypair -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 3650 -dname "CN=server,O=example.com" -keypass server-key-pass -keystore server-keystore.jks -storepass server-keystore-pass -ext san=dns:localhost
keytool -exportcert -alias server-keypair -file server-public-key.cer -keystore server-keystore.jks -storepass server-keystore-pass
keytool -importcert -keystore client-truststore.jks -alias server-public-key -file server-public-key.cer -storepass client-truststore-pass -noprompt
keytool -genkeypair -alias client-keypair -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 3650 -dname "CN=client,O=example.com" -keypass client-key-pass -keystore client-keystore.jks -storepass client-keystore-pass -ext san=dns:localhost
keytool -exportcert -alias client-keypair -file client-public-key.cer -keystore client-keystore.jks -storepass client-keystore-pass
keytool -importcert -keystore server-truststore.jks -alias client-public-key -file client-public-key.cer -storepass server-truststore-pass -noprompt
```

The client tries to access the server method '/ping' but fails:

> I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8443/ping":
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

As I suppose the problem in that it fails to find the corresponding trusted certificate. See the client and server logs.

The fragment of the client's log:

```html
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1492968872 bytes = { 122, 185, 155, 157, 162, 122, 13, 22, 130, 69, 5, 212, 104, 156, 236, 21, 7, 5, 10, 118, 225, 119, 204, 197, 119, 71, 218, 51 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 161
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1203
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1492968872 bytes = { 67, 233, 215, 38, 120, 118, 20, 192, 136, 203, 117, 93, 119, 58, 154, 49, 182, 103, 0, 120, 195, 147, 38, 22, 174, 224, 117, 60 }
Session ID:  {89, 253, 230, 168, 47, 236, 148, 163, 4, 86, 231, 18, 116, 107, 249, 240, 36, 144, 228, 219, 71, 77, 15, 66, 190, 167, 13, 226, 95, 238, 183, 143}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=server, O=example.com
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 16395633118756910027307786059594003602424782222606565910337550060908536298801174254632657544879537262094461451346219502757033857307571844657739767071036889717826387604089928884679390329877033966916175374004613622786740797504438976382866577264443059096891472723014174538058226555331443341009455479083583931320725095623525897039749701781104729471039035076119274189413857721785010757543567230018443782297097827183111043265398765503566151229256856786723441081439208963102430925580594555422331624337325788268369166029643139661336445322824913420707315576933941674401285439027030973786186023857115674616086965563274612260461
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Sat Nov 04 16:57:14 2017,
               To: Tue Nov 02 16:57:14 2027]
  Issuer: CN=server, O=example.com
  SerialNumber: [    40eb7950]

Certificate Extensions: 2
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: localhost
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F7 3F E9 03 D7 A4 AA C7   65 E8 CD 6D AB 70 FF F0  .?......e..m.p..
0010: EA E6 2F F0                                        ../.
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 34 BA 11 06 65 17 04 C2   5B 04 86 07 6C F1 92 F0  4...e...[...l...
0010: 4B F6 17 37 7E F8 47 1C   75 19 CF 75 22 10 82 4C  K..7..G.u..u"..L
0020: 83 35 A2 46 CC 1D 3A 92   98 27 8F 31 FC 85 F1 D2  .5.F..:..'.1....
0030: FC C2 20 27 C4 29 0F BE   2E 2F F1 0A 84 9F 9A 03  .. '.).../......
0040: 76 14 DD FB 6D E6 B6 AA   E4 1D 50 0E 18 A3 E7 19  v...m.....P.....
0050: 0F 10 1F 26 A7 92 FE 37   71 28 0C 4C 75 BC AF E0  ...&...7q(.Lu...
0060: F8 8A 42 87 EF 7E 01 25   F1 C7 40 8B AB F5 1C 4D  ..B....%..@....M
0070: AD AF 29 4C C4 71 8C 15   49 D6 E9 63 25 4D 92 49  ..)L.q..I..c%M.I
0080: 65 FC DD AA 41 1A F9 CB   01 DC D7 39 BD 67 5B CB  e...A......9.g[.
0090: BA FD 7E 3D 9D E2 DF 2D   C6 B8 C2 5A 3A 5C 06 ED  ...=...-...Z:\..
00A0: FC 86 1C 29 19 B8 2E A4   36 7C B0 09 67 A4 5E A2  ...)....6...g.^.
00B0: 31 7B C5 B7 E1 EC B3 4C   17 EE AE 0D B7 CF B0 67  1......L.......g
00C0: 3D C4 7F 1D D3 C1 C0 0C   42 8B 1A BC C6 71 5D A2  =.......B....q].
00D0: AF 12 54 F0 B2 23 E4 49   16 C3 1A 7A 62 C5 65 AE  ..T..#.I...zb.e.
00E0: B3 D3 D6 BF ED F1 D6 65   FA 70 96 BC 9A 1F 48 2B  .......e.p....H+
00F0: 71 49 6B 33 31 05 FF EF   38 26 4A BB C4 80 8F 58  qIk31...8&J....X

]
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
2017-11-04 19:11:20.818  INFO 1000 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-11-04 19:11:20.859 ERROR 1000 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at com.example.client.ClientApplication.main(ClientApplication.java:36) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8443/ping": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:666) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:312) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at com.example.client.ClientApplication.pingServer(ClientApplication.java:42) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.example.client.ClientApplication.run(ClientApplication.java:30) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:78) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        ... 40 common frames omitted

2017-11-04 19:11:20.863  INFO 1000 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6d21714c: startup date [Sat Nov 04 19:11:15 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-11-04 19:11:20.871  INFO 1000 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

The fragment of the server's log:

```html
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1492968872 bytes = { 122, 185, 155, 157, 162, 122, 13, 22, 130, 69, 5, 212, 104, 156, 236, 21, 7, 5, 10, 118, 225, 119, 204, 197, 119, 71, 218, 51 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
matching alias: server-keypair
Standard ciphersuite chosen: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
%% Negotiating:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1492968872 bytes = { 67, 233, 215, 38, 120, 118, 20, 192, 136, 203, 117, 93, 119, 58, 154, 49, 182, 103, 0, 120, 195, 147, 38, 22, 174, 224, 117, 60 }
Session ID:  {89, 253, 230, 168, 47, 236, 148, 163, 4, 86, 231, 18, 116, 107, 249, 240, 36, 144, 228, 219, 71, 77, 15, 66, 190, 167, 13, 226, 95, 238, 183, 143}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=server, O=example.com
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 16395633118756910027307786059594003602424782222606565910337550060908536298801174254632657544879537262094461451346219502757033857307571844657739767071036889717826387604089928884679390329877033966916175374004613622786740797504438976382866577264443059096891472723014174538058226555331443341009455479083583931320725095623525897039749701781104729471039035076119274189413857721785010757543567230018443782297097827183111043265398765503566151229256856786723441081439208963102430925580594555422331624337325788268369166029643139661336445322824913420707315576933941674401285439027030973786186023857115674616086965563274612260461
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Sat Nov 04 16:57:14 2017,
               To: Tue Nov 02 16:57:14 2027]
  Issuer: CN=server, O=example.com
  SerialNumber: [    40eb7950]

Certificate Extensions: 2
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: localhost
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F7 3F E9 03 D7 A4 AA C7   65 E8 CD 6D AB 70 FF F0  .?......e..m.p..
0010: EA E6 2F F0                                        ../.
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 34 BA 11 06 65 17 04 C2   5B 04 86 07 6C F1 92 F0  4...e...[...l...
0010: 4B F6 17 37 7E F8 47 1C   75 19 CF 75 22 10 82 4C  K..7..G.u..u"..L
0020: 83 35 A2 46 CC 1D 3A 92   98 27 8F 31 FC 85 F1 D2  .5.F..:..'.1....
0030: FC C2 20 27 C4 29 0F BE   2E 2F F1 0A 84 9F 9A 03  .. '.).../......
0040: 76 14 DD FB 6D E6 B6 AA   E4 1D 50 0E 18 A3 E7 19  v...m.....P.....
0050: 0F 10 1F 26 A7 92 FE 37   71 28 0C 4C 75 BC AF E0  ...&...7q(.Lu...
0060: F8 8A 42 87 EF 7E 01 25   F1 C7 40 8B AB F5 1C 4D  ..B....%..@....M
0070: AD AF 29 4C C4 71 8C 15   49 D6 E9 63 25 4D 92 49  ..)L.q..I..c%M.I
0080: 65 FC DD AA 41 1A F9 CB   01 DC D7 39 BD 67 5B CB  e...A......9.g[.
0090: BA FD 7E 3D 9D E2 DF 2D   C6 B8 C2 5A 3A 5C 06 ED  ...=...-...Z:\..
00A0: FC 86 1C 29 19 B8 2E A4   36 7C B0 09 67 A4 5E A2  ...)....6...g.^.
00B0: 31 7B C5 B7 E1 EC B3 4C   17 EE AE 0D B7 CF B0 67  1......L.......g
00C0: 3D C4 7F 1D D3 C1 C0 0C   42 8B 1A BC C6 71 5D A2  =.......B....q].
00D0: AF 12 54 F0 B2 23 E4 49   16 C3 1A 7A 62 C5 65 AE  ..T..#.I...zb.e.
00E0: B3 D3 D6 BF ED F1 D6 65   FA 70 96 BC 9A 1F 48 2B  .......e.p....H+
00F0: 71 49 6B 33 31 05 FF EF   38 26 4A BB C4 80 8F 58  qIk31...8&J....X

]
***
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 92416907423797917108651411220949227236045261472538924138175892631080121076586
  public y coord: 52570159133152996394643964235748475641135431426241901245432881975987053534228
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
*** ServerHelloDone
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1203
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, certificate_unknown
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2, called closeOutbound()
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2, closeOutboundInternal()
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
```

The source code and full logs are presented [here](https://github.com/oxaoo/ssl-comm).

What could be the problem? Advise how it can be solved.